# how can i add zeros to file data using UNIX commands

Tags: unix

I have input format like below.

- first filed should be 9 digit
- second field should be 5 digit
- third filed should 5 digit before decimal
- fourth filed should be append without comma (comma should be removed).

Input:

```
100574,1,2.66,SB        
574155582,1,2.47,SB
```

I need the output as below format

```
0001005740000100002.66SB  
5741555820000100002.47SB
```

How do I make a script that would do this?

Comment: Use the awk program.

Comment: how to use thw awk command. please provide the command for the given output

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work - you may need to fiddle with the specific values of your printf statements.

```
cat input | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {printf "%09d", $1; printf "%05d", %2; printf "%05.2f", $3; printf "%s", $4 };'
```

If your problem gets any more complex I would recommend going to python or another more advanced language.

If you get stuck try looking at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: this command is not working as expected.

Comment: I missed the trailing single quote - try again.